# .htaccess url rewriting scheme not working in the server. in localhost it works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, koding

I have installed php 5.59 and apach2 2.4.7 installed in my koding.com VPS. I have a working .htaccess file which is (not very clean at the moment) locally running without any problem. How ever when I have uploaded the site into the server it is working funny. Theres one URL like this

```
http://bhashithe.koding.io/forum/read/need-to-check-the-answer-counter-works
```

I have added the re-writing scheme like this

```
RewriteRule ^read/(.*)$ /read.php?url=$1
```

But when I open that link it is re-directed to this

```
http://bhashithe.koding.io/forum/read.php?url=need-to-check-the-answer-counter-works
```

How ever that link is working ok. But when I open other links those return the 404 error perfectly re-directed to the one I have mentioned in the .htaccess file.

I am including the whole file for your reference.

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bhashithe.koding.io [NC] 

RewriteRule ^read/(.*)$ /read.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)$ /creator.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ ./category.php?category=$1
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ ./tag.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^index.html$ ./post.php
RewriteRule ^$ ./post.php
RewriteRule ^login$ ./login.php
RewriteRule ^new/$ ./creator.php
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ ./profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^login/(.*)$ ./login.php?response=$1
RewriteRule ^settings/(.*)$ ./settings.php?response=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ ./forum/profile.php?username=$1&feedback=$2

ErrorDocument 404 /forum/error.php
```

If theres anything that i am doing wrong please be kind enough to point that out.
Thank you,
Bhashithe

Comment: is mod rewrite enabled in apache?

Comment: Changed the names of the files and in the htaccess files rules. now it works :O

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your server with SSH

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Seems that your rewrite mod is not enabled on your server (but is on you local machine).

Comment: I am used to do this whenever i change anything inside the .htaccess file. might i need a httpd restart?

Comment: I have an ubuntu server in this it seems. how ever theres no httpd. I am more used to crunchbang :D

Comment: uBuntu's web server service is called apache2 not httpd